# Copy a list item with all field entries

Tags: javascript, list-item

I try to find an easy solution for copying a list items with all field values (duplicate a list item) and edit some specific lines at the end.

The script I'm using right now isn't perfect for my needs, because I have to copy every single field one by one and I want a script that does this automatically. E.g. copy list item '2' and edit title to a new one. Not 'copy title, copy entryDate, copy hours, copy... edit title.

```
        var updateXML = "<Batch OnError='Continue' PreCalc='TRUE'>";
        var index = 1;

        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            var title = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
            var entryDate = $(this).attr("ows_Entry_x0020_Date");
            var hours = $(this).attr("ows_Hours");

            updateXML = updateXML + "<Method ID='" + index++ + "' Cmd='New'>" +
                    "<Field Name='Title' Type='String'>" + title  +  "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Entry_x0020_Date' Type='Date'>" + entryDate +  "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='Hours' Type='Number'>" + hours +  "</Field>" +
                    "<Field Name='IssueID' Type='Number'>" + newParentID +  "</Field>" +
                    "</Method>";
         });

        updateXML = updateXML + "</Batch>";
```

Comment: why are you editing the xml? you could access the field you want to change directly from the list item

Comment: I also recommend creating a workflow (with "Copy List Item" action) in Sharepoint Designer. Then you can add a "Duplicate" button into the ribbon to make this feature available to the users. To do so you can have a look at http://ranaictiu-technicalblog.blogspot.fr/2010/06/sharepoint-2010-add-button-to-ribbon.html

Answer (score 1):

I recommend creating custom workflow using SharePoint Designer. In the workflow, use the "Copy List Item" action to copy the item.

Blog article containing full step-by-step instructions can be found [here](http://blogs.salmanghani.info/copy-item-workflow-using-sharepoint-designer-2010/).